# How to embed SQLite in a Windows Form Application?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, sqlite

After learning how to use SQL this past semester, I would like to put it to use in an application. After coming upon the realization that my application would require SQL Server software installed in order for it to work, I asked around and was directed to SQLite.

I'm wondering if anyone can give a quick tutorial on how to use SQLite with a Windows Form Application, or direct me to one (I can't seem to find one).

Answer (score 2):

[deploying winform application with embedded sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689628/deploying-winform-application-with-embedded-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider SQLCE (Compact Edition). It is a free sql implementation from microsoft. Last time I looked at SQL Lite I think it was out of development (I'm sure someone will correct me if I am wrong).
SQLCE is easy to use from visual studio and sql server managagement studio. Anyone using your application will need the runtime installed or you can build your deployment to handle that.